# Play Framework 2.1: BodyParser class file missing

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I downloaded Play Framework 2.1 and after `eclipsifying` it I have `errors` in controllers, and target folder.

In controller, `Application.scala` I have the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - class file needed by BodyParser is missing. reference type Either of object package refers to nonexisting 
     symbol.
```

If any of you got this errors, how have you fixed it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Play 2.1 uses Scala 2.10. If you downloaded the Play 2.1 SNAPSHOT just now, your problem is likely due to the Scala IDE which still uses 2.9.X. The error will not show if you compile the project with `play compile` (as SBT will use the correct Scala library version), but it will show in the IDE until you upgrade it.

To upgrade Scala IDE, please follow the instructions on [their website](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala_ide_21_milestone_2).

By the way, don't forget that the command `eclipsify` was renamed to `eclipse` in Play 2.1.

Comment: yes thanks. That's the cause. Didn't think of that but you're right. Thanks once again

Comment: Awesome! spend a couple hours on this. Just to note, the url that is given should be pasted in the `install new software` section. I had a brain fart and couldn't figure out what to do with it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the solution is that the latest eclipse (Juno) is not working with the latest Scala IDE plugin, just with a nightly build: http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-juno-master-29x/ 
... which supports only scala 2.9.

So: is there a way to develop a Play 2.1 project with Eclipse Juno?

Comment: Yes, on [the Scala IDE page](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html) under _Update Site for Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno)_ and _For Scala 2.10.0_, click the url and it'll pop up with a reminder on how to install the latest 2.10 plugin in Eclipse.